# PHP Contact Form not displaying

Tags: php, html

I have some problems displaying a message on the website when the message has been sent
Just to be quick I will explain what I have done and what is not working

**HTML code**

```
<div class="col-lg-8 mt-5 mt-lg-0">
<form action="contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mt-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mt-3">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="my-3">
    <div class="loading">Loading</div>
    <div class="error-message"></div>
    <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```php
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != ''  ) {
    if ( filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $to = 'receiver_email address';
        $body = "";
        $body .= "From: ".$name. "\r\n";
        $body .= "Email: ".$email. "\r\n";
        $body .= "Message: ".$message. "\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $body);
        echo "<h2>Message Sent</h2>"; }}
?>
```

Screen shoot with what I receive when I've sent the message

[Screen shoot with what I receive when I've sent the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BPXQ.jpg)

Is there a way I can modify my PHP code to be able to display the text from HTML

```html
<div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button>
<div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>?
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: If you want to display the SAME page when you submit the form and not go to the contact.php then you need to use javascript to submit the form via something like ajax.

Comment: Yes, you need to make it an AJAX request, get the response and use Javascript to update your DOM accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for that you can use sessions.

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != ''  ) {
    if ( filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $to = 'receiver_email address';
        $body = "";
        $body .= "From: ".$name. "\r\n";
        $body .= "Email: ".$email. "\r\n";
        $body .= "Message: ".$message. "\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $body);
 
        // Put the message inside the session
        $_SESSION['success_message']="<h2>Message Sent</h2>"; 

        // Here you may redirect somewhere if needed. 

}}
?>
```

Then in Html:

```
    <?php session_start();
    
    <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button>
    ?>

<?php
    
    if(isset($_SESSION['success_message'] )) {
       echo $_SESSION['success_message'];
    
       // Dont forget to delete the message from the session once displayed.
       unset($_SESSION['success_message']) ;
    }
    
    ?>
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution doesn't work :(

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work ? any error or any output are you getting?

Comment: I have pasted the HTML code you provided, and when I reload the page see some code [link](https://ibb.co/cJGSZLT)

Comment: The message is sent successfully, but it returns "Error: Form submission failed and no error message returned from: contact.php"